# How to find the Sum of a complex Alternating Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

So I know the mechanics of how you're supposed to solve this sort of problem, but this one requires algebraic gymnastics that I just can't seem to think my way through.

The question:

> Find the sum of the series:
>   $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(-1)^n\frac{2^{n+1}}{5^{n-1}n!}$$

After almost an hour of chasing my own tail, I just can't get everything to line up correctly.

One step will obviously involve changing the starting point from $n=1$ to $n=0$, altering the powers of $n$ and $n$-factorial within the sigma as a result, but I can't find out how to rewrite it in such a way that everything clicks into place when I take that step.

EDIT:: In response to HINT

Ok here's what I've got:

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(-1)^n\frac{2^{n+1}}{5^{n-1}n!}$$
$$=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(-1)^n\frac{2\times2^n}{\frac{1}{5}\times5^nn!}$$
$$=10\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(-1)^n(\frac{2}{5})^n\frac{1}{n!}$$
$$=10+10\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(-1)^n(\frac{2}{5})^n\frac{1}{n!}-10$$
$$=10(1+\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(-1)^n(\frac{2}{5})^n\frac{1}{n!}-1)$$
$$\large=10(e^{-\frac{2}{5}}-1) = \frac{10}{e^{\frac{2}{5}}}+10$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:**

The series for $e^{-x}$ is given by

$$e^{-x}=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^n}{n!} \tag 1$$

Can you proceed from here?

**SPOILER ALERT**  Scroll over the highlighted are to reveal the solution.

> Starting from $(1)$, we see that $$e^{-x}-1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^n}{n!}\tag 2$$  Then, letting $x=2/5$ and multiplying $(2)$ by $10$ yields $$10\left(e^{-2/5}-1\right)=10\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(2/5)^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(2)^{n+1}}{5^{n-1}n!}$$and we are done!

Comment: Thank you! This might be the trick, Please stand by a few minutes while I work through it with this in mind.

Comment: You're welcome.   My pleasure.  I've added a Spoiler Alert section if you become stuck.

Comment: Hey I did it without having to look at the spoiler! Maybe I'm not hopelessly over my head after all.

Comment: Awesome!  Pleased to hear.  Well done